# Is there a way that regex replacement only replaces text and not the characters elements like span> which then breaks the html code?

Tags: javascript, regex

when i replace one character 'a' with a wrapped span, a styling of the color and the same letter with regex replace() function it works. and it also works if i run it a second time. but on the third time it starts to replace also the letters within the  tag which then breaks the code. is there a way to replace only the text and not the already replaced letters?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>

    <div id="lettersList">aabbccd</div>


<script>
a = '<span style="color: #d94a6f;">a</span>';
b = '<span style="color: #3a97f7;">b</span>';
c ='<span style="color: #fffa73;">c</span>';
d = '<span style="color: #8747f6;">d</span>';
e = '<span style="color: #454545;">e</span>';
f = '<span style="color: #8ef271;">f</span>';
g = '<span style="color: #f29737;">g</span>';
h = '<span style="color: #d1a239;">h</span>';
i = '<span style="color: #70f9fd;">i</span>';
j = '<span style="color: #f091d4;">j</span>';
k = '<span style="color: #a957e5;">k</span>';
l = '<span style="color: #4f3aec;">l</span>';
m = '<span style="color: #e18695;">m</span>';
n = '<span style="color: #faec75;">n</span>';
o = '<span style="color: #ffffff;">o</span>';
p = '<span style="color: #cb63ef;">p</span>';
q = '<span style="color: #d2bfb7;">q</span>';
r = '<span style="color: #f091d4;">r</span>';
s = '<span style="color: #ec4025;">s</span>';
t = '<span style="color: #57964d;">t</span>';
u = '<span style="color: #e5bf74;">u</span>';
v = '<span style="color: #f29840;">v</span>';
w = '<span style="color: #fffa8c;">w</span>';
x = '<span style="color: #a97f40;">x</span>';
y = '<span style="color: #fae085;">y</span>';
z = '<span style="color: #4b258d;">z</span>';

function blackc(id, regg, aaa){
const elt = document.getElementById(id);
 elt.innerHTML = elt.innerHTML.replace(regg, aaa);
}

blackc('lettersList', /a/g, a);
blackc('lettersList', /b/g, b);
blackc('lettersList', /c/g, c);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: although achieving that with regexp is technically possible it needs a lot of efforts and solution will not be maintainable. better to use specialized parser and traverse trough its outcomes. what environment you are targeting? browser? nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended using regex to manipulate HTML

Perhaps this is more useful?

```js
const colors = {"a":"#d94a6f;","b":"#3a97f7;","c":"#fffa73;","d":"#8747f6;","e":"#454545;","f":"#8ef271;","g":"#f29737;","h":"#d1a239;","i":"#70f9fd;","j":"#f091d4;","k":"#a957e5;","l":"#4f3aec;","m":"#e18695;","n":"#faec75;","o":"#ffffff;","p":"#cb63ef;","q":"#d2bfb7;","r":"#f091d4;","s":"#ec4025;","t":"#57964d;","u":"#e5bf74;","v":"#f29840;","w":"#fffa8c;","x":"#a97f40;","y":"#fae085;","z":"#4b258d;"}

let ll = document.getElementById("lettersList")
ll.innerHTML = ll.innerText.split("").map(l => `<span style="color:${colors[l]}">${l}</span>`).join("")
```

```html
<div id="lettersList">aabbccd</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using CSS would be better for the coloring, I modified the function to wrap each letter passed into the `blackc` with a span that colors the text, if no list of letters are passed it wraps every non-whitespace letter in the string.

```js
function blackc(id, letters=["\\w"]) {
  let reg = RegExp(`<[^>]+>|(${letters.join("|")})`, 'gi');
  let el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(reg, `<span class="$1">$1</span>`);
}

blackc('lettersList1');
blackc('lettersList2', ["a", "c"]);
```

```css
.a {
  color: #d94a6f;
}

.b {
  color: #3a97f7;
}

.c {
  color: #fffa73;
}

.d {
  color: #8747f6;
}

.e {
  color: #454545;
}

.f {
  color: #8ef271;
}

.g {
  color: #f29737;
}

.h {
  color: #d1a239;
}

.i {
  color: #70f9fd;
}

.j {
  color: #f091d4;
}

.k {
  color: #a957e5;
}

.l {
  color: #4f3aec;
}

.m {
  color: #e18695;
}

.n {
  color: #faec75;
}

.o {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.p {
  color: #cb63ef;
}

.q {
  color: #d2bfb7;
}

.r {
  color: #f091d4;
}

.s {
  color: #ec4025;
}

.t {
  color: #57964d;
}

.u {
  color: #e5bf74;
}

.v {
  color: #f29840;
}

.w {
  color: #fffa8c;
}

.x {
  color: #a97f40;
}

.y {
  color: #fae085;
}

.z {
  color: #4b258d;
}
```

```html
<div id="lettersList1">
  aabb c8cd
</div><div id="lettersList2">
  aabb c8cd
</div>
```